# How to integrate SonarCloud with GitHub and Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, github, sonarcloud

I just concluded my GitHub integration with Jenkins so that every time I commit code to my GitHub repository, Jenkins automatically builds. 
Now I'm trying to integrate SonarCloud too but I haven't been successful.
I'm not looking to integrate with a local SonarQube server, I really need SonarCloud for my team to check it every time Jenkins builds.

I'm not sure if I should analyse the project locally to achieve this or if I can analyse my Jenkins server or GitHub repository and get the result I want because I can't find any documentation.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Sonarcloud is just a sonarqube server.

Just use [sonar-scanner](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner/)(the documentation for jenkins can be found [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-jenkins/)).

At first, you need to install the [jenkins plugin for sonar-scanner](https://plugins.jenkins.io/sonar/).

After that, you open the configuration of sonar-scanner using `Manage Jenkins > Configure System`.

Insert `https://sonarcloud.io` under `Server URL` and your sonar token(of sonarclound) under `Server authentication token`

[image: image showing how to configure it]

Under `Manage Jenkins > Configure System`, you should check `Enable injection of SonarQube server configuration as build environment variables` and in `Build Environment` in your job, you should enable `Prepare SonarScanner environment`.

After you've done that, you can run sonar-scanner with `$SONAR_MAVEN_GOAL` (if you are using maven), `./gradlew sonarqube` (if you are using gradle) or `sonar-scanner` (if you use none of that).